# arrayForEach was called with a non array value. Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am trying to get events from my Calendar. I walked through all tutorials and searched through internet, but it seems like i am the only one who get the error. My calendar oppened for everyone. **ClientId**, **Api key**, **DISCOVERY_DOCS** and **SCOPES** are correct, because i purposly made them wrong to check. Also i tried to change **calendarId** from 'primary' to actual calendar id, which is my email address. Same story. I **am** signed in and approved, so it is not the problem for sure. There **are** events in my Calendar, so it should have an array anyway. Looks like it doesn't get the array on some part of code and it is not possible for me to debug it step by step. At this point i completely don't understand what is wrong.

So the code straight from this tutorial [JavaScript Google Calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js), only CLIENT_ID and API_KEY changed, and there is no point inserting the same code here i guess.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when using visual studio with .net core. I found a problem with the file "browser-sync-client.js". I blocked the request to this file and it worked. So I change to use pure HTML,js without the visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue since I upgraded to VisualStudio 2022, I don't know if it's usefull. I didn't understand how to fix it yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31644629)